# Sharepoint URL not able to acess through SQL agent Job

Tags: sql, sharepoint, ssis, sql-agent-job

I am running a sql server job which is loading data from a file kept in a sharepoint document library.File is an excel format and is getting loaded when executed through solution .But when i am using an SQL Agent job to pick up the file it doesnt get the path and agent job fails.I have deployed the SSIS Package through SQL Server 2012 deployment methodologies.I am not able to trace the error of loading data from a sharepoint library.library. Sql agent jobs works fine when i give local path.The account which is running the sql agent job is the same who has access to document library.I also tried to run the job through proxy but then a strange error comes of error authenticating proxy:unknown username and password whereas my password and username are all correct.I am in between of my deployment to production and facing such issue from a long time.

Comment: What is the Operating system of the server that the SQL agent job is on?

Comment: I am using window server 2012 operating system and my SQL Agents jobs are deployed over the same